# Aspose.Cells for .NET is taking long time to read a Stream (on one machine only!)

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose-cells

In an MVC5 application with .NET 4.6.1 with IIS Express on Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. I tried both Aspose.Cells v8.9.1 and 16.10.0 .

```
Workbook excelWorkbook = new Workbook(uploadFile.InputStream);
```

This line takes huge amount of time (an hour or so), even for the the smallest possible Excel file. On the other hand, on production machine and other developer machines, it is taking no time.

I tried reading uploadFile.InputStream into a byte[] just to make sure that ASPOSE is not having a trouble with this stream, and copying to bytes takes no time.

I even started trying this, but the same problem still exists:

```
LoadOptions loadOptions = new LoadOptions(LoadFormat.Xlsx);
loadOptions.MemorySetting = MemorySetting.MemoryPreference;
Workbook excelWorkbook = new Workbook(uploadFile.InputStream, loadOptions);
```

I have been having this problem for months and during this time, I have restarted my machine and Visual Studio several times.

**Any clue of what is causing the time delay?**

Comment: If you first load it into a MemoryStream, are you saying this takes no time on the problematic machine? What then if you load from that MemoryStream, same problem?

Comment: @Adam, 

I believe you have posted a similar inquiry in Aspose.Cells support forum as well. Please note, I have tried the case while using the latest version of Aspose.Cells for .NET 16.10.0 in a sample MVC5 project, however, I was not able to replicate the issue. Please share an executable sample application [in Aspose.Cells support thread] along with dependencies to reproduce the problem.